Lint warning in android studio
Please tell me if there is any way to disable logging of such warnings when building a project:
`> Task :app:mergeStageResources
/builds/client-side/platform-specific/mobile/mobile-android/mobile-android/lib/libui/build/.transforms/fa2c5bac03c754a79970e0210e03bb59/transformed/jetified-libui/res/values/values.xml:1669:4: Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format of string resource string/accessibility_selected_range. Did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?`

These warnings arise because of the row resources that lie in a separate aar project, and there is no way to edit the file.
I tried to add rules for lint in gradle file to the app module, something like this:
`lint {
        lint.abortOnError = false
        disable.addAll(listOf("StringFormatMatches", "StringFormatInvalid"))
        lintConfig = rootProject.file("lint.xml")
        disable += "StringFormatMatches"
    }`

I also tried to add rules to lint.xml That's it:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="StringFormatMatches">
        <ignore path="**values.xml" />
    </issue>
</lint>`

None of this helps, maybe there are some other solutions? I will be grateful for your advice!
